# can't add a remove/edit feature to my program

Tags: javascript

I making a web app that can be used to store contacts. I am having trouble with a feature in which I use a button to either remove or edit a contact. I have tried something like this.

```html
<doctype html>
  <html>

  <head></head>

  <body>
    <table>
      <thead></thead>
      <tbody id='add-to'></tbody>
    </table>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      // holds all the buttons Id's so I can keep track of which button I pressed
      var id_hold = []
       $(document).ready(function() {

        for (var i = 0; i < id_hold; i++) {
          // should add print something to the console if any button is clicked
          $('#' + id_hold[i]).click(function() {
            console.log('clicked button ' + i);
          });

        }

        addIds();

      });

      function addIds() {
        // allows me to add things to the table I made above
        var add_to_dom = $('#add-to');

        for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
          add_to_dom.append('<button id =' + i + '></button>');
        }
      }
      }
    </script>
  </body>

  </html>
```

My question is how do make Add a feature like this that works? I don't know how to.
thanks

Comment: Sorry for the misleading title, I tried asking a question i never posted a few weeks back and this website saved it as a draft, and I forgot to change the title

Comment: You *could* edit the title.  There's no need to apologize, just change it to a more appropriate one.

Comment: What is it exactly that you don't know? If your question is not more clearly specified (input, and expected output), you will not get answer. Keep in mind that this is not a code factory. You are supposed to do some minimal research on your own.

Comment: What I don't know is how trigger button actions from buttons the program adds to the html file

Answer (score 0):

As @user3743222 said you should do a bit of research before asking a question and need to be specific on what you want to achieve. Your posted code doesn't even run because of extra }. Anyway assuming you want to get this working I made some minimal changes to get that working.

```
<doctype html>
<html>

<head></head>

<body>
<table>
    <thead></thead>
    <div id='add-to'></div>
</table>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    // holds all the buttons Id's so I can keep track of which button I pressed
    var id_hold = []
    $(document).ready(function () {


        addIds();

        for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            // should add print something to the console if any button is clicked
            (function (j) {
                $('#' + id_hold[j]).click(function () {
                    console.log('clicked button ' + j);
                });
            })(i)

        }
    });

    function addIds() {
        // allows me to add things to the table I made above
        var add_to_dom = $('#add-to');

        for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            add_to_dom.append('<button id =' + i + '>' + i + ' </button>');
            id_hold[i] = i;
        }
    }

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Please note that you need to wrap click binding function inside for loop in a self invoking scope to avoid the case where you get the same i value for all the click handlers.